# Loop Invariant Code Motion not tagging an expression correctly

Tags: optimization, compilers

I was reading the LICM section of the book Advanced Compiler Design and Implementation and found me questioning why the expression `d = -c` wasn't tagged as invariant.

It isn't hard to see that `c = 2` is invariant given its operand is a constant. Then, since `d = -c` is taking an invariant operand, then `d` also should be invariant.

What point am I missing here?

[image: LICM]

Comment: run the loop for a lesser iterations $(i>3)$ and you'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Rinkesh is correct. The expression $-c$ is loop-invariant (and can be constant-propagated to the value $-2$), but the assignment $d \leftarrow -c$ is not because the assignment in block B4 might execute instead.

If you're still not convinced, try converting it to static single assignment (SSA) form.

Comment: Oh, I get it, I thought the right-side expression was what mattered, but I can't move the assignment to `d` upside when `d` might get another assignment.